# Wordpress wp-admin error 403 files in wp-admin are accessable

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, plesk, wp-admin

I have a blog running and everything seems to be fine.

But I cannot access

/wp-admin/ ==> 403

it is only that directory, which is not accessable...

I can easily access /wp-admin/edit.php and every other file within this directory (also /wp-admin/index.php is working...)

directory permission is set to 755

htaccess from blog root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Die Anweisungen (Zeilen) zwischen „BEGIN WordPress“ und „END WordPress“ sind
# dynamisch generiert und sollten nur über WordPress-Filter geändert werden.
# Alle Änderungen an den Anweisungen zwischen diesen Markierungen werden überschrieben.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Website is running on a root server with plesk installed.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

thank you so much
cheers
D

Comment: What is `DirectoryIndex` set to?

Comment: sorry but I am not sure what you mean by this question, can you please help me where I can find this setting?

Comment: What I am talking about is https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex, and it can be set in multiple places. Try and set it yourself in your .htaccess, with `index.php` as the default file name to look for.

Comment: Okay thank you. I put a new .htaccess-file to the wp-admin dir with the following content "DirectoryIndex index.php" ... unfortunately without success - no change in behaviour

Comment: It must have something to do with the web application firewall from plesk, when I deactivate everything works fine

Comment: Then you should check the logs to see which rule caused this, and disable it (if you are sure this doesn't affect anything else negatively) - https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/server-administration/web-application-firewall-modsecurity.73383/#switching-off-rules explains the process.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing web application firewall from Comodo to Atomic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the 403 error for `/wordpress/wp-admin/` by disabling the `ModSecurity` rule `CWAF` in Plesk.